# Охват дочерних элементов родительским абсолютно позиционированным блоком

Tags: html, css

Есть спойлер при раскрытии которого есть контент (причем немалых размеров, где то под 100 а то и больше элементов), в нем есть особенность - направление контента не слева направо а ***сверху вниз***. Высота задается/ограничивается через max-height.
Поискав на тему заполнения блока контентом сверху вниз нашел сие [arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float](https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/). И пример оттуда (уже модифицированный мной) для случаев многих элементов - [pen by anonymous](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOyWmQ)

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
```

Возникла проблема - у меня родительский ul абсолютно спозиционирован, и нужно чтобы его красный фон охватывал все внутренние элементы. Как это сделать?

Comment: добавить width: 100%;

Comment: Контент динамический, может быть 2 элемента, а может 102